# Relative path to css and js files is incorrect when browser's url is changed

Tags: reactjs, react-router

**history.js**

```
var createBrowserHistory = require('history/lib/createBrowserHistory');

var history = createBrowserHistory();

module.exports = history;
```

**routes.js**:

```jsx
'use strict';
var React = require('react'),
    ReactRouter = require('react-router'),
    Router = ReactRouter.Router,
    Route = ReactRouter.Route,
    NotFoundRoute = ReactRouter.NotFoundRoute,
    IndexRoute = require('react-router').IndexRoute,
    history = require('./history.js'),
    App = require('./components/app.js'),
    SignupPage = require('./components/signupPage/signupPage.js'),
    SignupSuccessPage = require('./components/signupSuccessPage/signupSuccessPage.js'),
    NotFoundPage = require('./components/notFoundPage/notFoundPage.js');

var routes = (
  <Router history={history}>
    <Route path='/(:languageCode)' component={App} >
      <IndexRoute component={SignupPage} />
      <Route path='/success' component={SignupSuccessPage} />
      <Route path='*' component={NotFoundPage} />
    </Route>
  </Router>
);

module.exports = routes;
```

**index.html**:

```html
<html lang="en">
  <head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
    <title>signup page</title>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="css/bundle.css" />
    <script src="scripts/vendors.bundle.js" type="text/javascript" defer></script>
    <script src="scripts/bundle.js" type="text/javascript" defer></script>
  </head>
  <body>
    <div id="app"></div>
  </body>
</html>
```

Loading url : `http://localhost:9005/en` (works as expected)
Loading url: `http://localhost:9005/fr` (works as expected)

However loading url: `http://localhost:9005/en/success` (does NOT work as expected)

In google's developer console I see requests to files:

```
http://localhost:9005/en/css/bundle.css 
http://localhost:9005/en/scripts/vendors.bundle.js 
http://localhost:9005/en/scripts/vendors.vendor.js
```

However if you look at the `index.html` file above the urls should be

```
http://localhost:9005/css/bundle.css 
http://localhost:9005/scripts/vendors.bundle.js 
http://localhost:9005/scripts/vendors.vendor.js
```

I am not sure how /en/ is part of the urls for .css and .js files.

Answer (score 1):

I also faced the same issue.
Actually when we are going to a route at 1 level deep in react-router-dom like:

```
localhost:3000/list
```

it works fine. When we go to a route containing more than one level like:

```
localhost:3000/list/business
```

It doesn't work and just concatenates the CSS relative path at the end of the pathname. Its a weird behaviour with `react-router-dom`.

But a workaround is to add prefix the pathnames with `"%PUBLIC_URL%"`:

```html
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="%PUBLIC_URL%/style.css" />
```

Here `style.css` should be present in your public folder.

Answer (score -1):

The reason why your `http://localhost:9005/en/success` work as expected is because you defined your route path with the `/` in the beginning which means that you are declaring absolute path. If you remove that `/` you will get what you expect. See how the [Route Matching](https://github.com/rackt/react-router/blob/master/docs/guides/basics/RouteMatching.md) works.

so your routes should look like:

```jsx
var createBrowserHistory = require('history/lib/createBrowserHistory');
var history = createBrowserHistory();

var routes = (
  <Router history={history}>
    <Route path='/(:languageCode)' component={App}>
      <IndexRoute component={SignupPage} />
      <Route path='success' component={SignupSuccessPage} />
      <Route path='*' component={NotFoundPage} />
    </Route>
  </Router>
);
```

Comment: thanks for the reply. I changed my code to be identical to your solution however the problem still persists. I have included the the the way i've set up my history, please check history.js on top. Could it have something to do with the way history.js is setup?

Comment: oh yeah, you need to `var createBrowserHistory = require('history/lib/createBrowserHistory')` and then: `var history = createBrowserHistory()` sorry, just realised you have that already...